# How to do remote debugging with Nsight 5.5 on Linux?

Tags: cuda, nsight, gdbserver, cuda-gdb

***Disclaimer:** I know that this question has been asked numerous times, but before Nsight 5.5 the answer simply was "You can't."*

I'm trying to debug a CUDA program with Nsight 5.5 on Ubuntu. The remote machine is also an Ubuntu with CUDA Toolkit 5.5.

I setup debugging in NSight using the "Debug an application on a remote system".
Whenever I try to run the application I get a "Could not start gdbserver on the remote host" error.

This is what I get on the console:

```
Last login: Thu Aug  1 16:09:26 2013 from host.whatever.edu
echo $PWD'>'
 :2345 /tmp/nsight-debug/flow;exit
someuser@remotehost:~$ echo $PWD'>'
/home/someuser>
someuser@remotehost:~$  :2345 /tmp/nsight-debug/flow;exit
:2345: command not found
logout
```

Both `gdbserver` and `cuda-gdbserver` are installed on both machines.

If I ssh to the remote host, I can run `/tmp/nsight-debug/flow` manually.

What might be the problem here? Is there anything missing from the setup?

Comment: Did you follow all the steps in the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nsight-eclipse-edition-getting-started-guide/index.html#remote-debugging) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Nsight, we will take a look into this matter.

Please make sure that you have remote toolkit configured for your connection.

1. From the main menu, select *Run* -> *Debug Configurations...*
2. In the left-hand tree, select you debug configuration under *C/C++ Remote Application*
3. Make sure that *Remote toolkit* combo has proper toolkit selected. If you don't have any toolkit configured, click *Manage...* and setup the toolkit.

Usually you will only have to setup the toolkit once per your connection - e.g. you will not have to setup it if you want to debug another application on the same remote system.