# Nsight eclipse for linux remote debugging error

Tags: eclipse, debugging, cuda, nsight, cuda-gdb

I'm using ubuntu12.10 x64 on my notebook and the nsight eclipse for linux to write cuda programs and I am trying to debug it on a server running CentOS6.0 x64 with 2 Geforce GTX 260 display cards. Both computers have installed the cuda toolkit 5.5, yet when I tried to start the debugger, I got an error from the nsight, which says:

> Launching failed.
>
> java.lang.reflect.invocationTargetException

I don't know what happened and how to solve this problem, is there anyone who encountered this situation and know how to do? Please tell me!

Comment: Have you followed the [instructions in the documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nsight-eclipse-edition-getting-started-guide/index.html#remote-debugging) for remote debugging?  Also, this recent [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006253/how-to-do-remote-debugging-with-nsight-5-5-on-linux) may be of interest.

Comment: yes, I configured the environment as the cuda instruction said. Actually I have done it several times after I got this error, yet it still doesn't work. what should I do?

Comment: Are you able to run the CUDA program normally on the CentOS 6 server (i.e. locally, or from an SSH console, not via remote debugging) ?

Comment: Is there anything in your Console view? Can you check log file contents at ~/cuda-workspace/.metadata/.log? Can you debug non-CUDA applications (e.g. "hello world") locally in Nsight?

Comment: Yes, I can run the CUDA program normally on my CentOS 6 server. Also I can use the Nsight to debug my program. It works well.

Comment: Hi, Eugene, I can use nsight to debug my C/C++ applications locally, and I checked my log file, it says:
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Failed to execute MI command: 
-target-select remote 192.168.2.105:2345 
Error message from debugger back end: 
192.168.2.105:2345: No route to host. What should I do?